# Angular2 Timeout operator doesn't work on extended Http

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

When I extend `Http` class to add a timeout setter using rxjs, the `timeout` operator doesn't work when I import it like this `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'`

It only works when I load the entire rxjs library

[live plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kQTFLWjZ8lEtlN3Oe1wu?p=preview)

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'
import {HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend} from "@angular/http";

import {WpHttp} from "../wpHttp";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(private wpHttp: WpHttp) {
    //this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.wpHttp.get("../test.json").subscribe((res)=>{
      this.name = res.title;
    });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: WpHttp,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
        new WpHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]

    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Extended Http

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class WpHttp extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
              defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }


  get(url): Observable<any> {

    console.log("started")
    return super.get(url)

      .timeout("500", new Error('delay exceeded'))
      .catch((err) => {
        return Observable.throw(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("finished")
      });
  }


}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the problem is related to the fact that `timeout()` is used in a class that extends `Http` as stated in the title.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it works with the commented code in the plnkr but just when I used it in the extended http, I got the error

Comment: And when you use timout it with `http.get()` directly (without the custom `WpHttp`)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes it works with the normal `http.get()`

Comment: Shouldn't `timeout` take a number, not a string?

Comment: More weird is when I import the entire rxjs library it works @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: `timeout` will convert the string to a number because it uses `Math.abs()` internally. Have you tried moving the import into the file where you are doing the extension?

Comment: @paulpdaniels yup ofcourse

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I opened this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12258) on github but DzmitryShylovich said it doesn't fall into the bug report, can you report it to angular team?

Comment: I'm also not convinced this is a bug. I don't know rxjs well enough to debug the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed by adding all the used operators

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```